# How to search only for "tag's" in mediawiki, not whole text

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediaWiki and the users are requesting the following feature :

They want to add keywords/tags to articles so people can search for these keywords.

But they they also want that the search engine ONLY searches for these keywords/tags. And not for text in the article itself.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are called [categories](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories) in MediaWiki. Search support is not great but with the `CirrusSearch` extension you can use the [`incategory:`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Filters_.28intitle:.2C_incategory:_and_linksto:.29) keyword to filter search results to the given categories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would have to drastically change your database in order for every article to be able to have a number of tags. You could then adapt the search box to not only look through the articles, but also the tags. As for the exclusive search, you would probably need to add some checkboxes to your style next to the search box, link them to the searchbox, and make it search through tags only. I am not aware of any plugin featuring this, but there may be one.

[Check them out here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Extensions)

Comment: Yes! All the fun! But it is not impossible if you know your way around SQL, HTML and CSS... and also PHP.